# Ошибка при компиляции скрипта python в файл .exe при помощи pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Есть проект на python, где используется библиотека pyproj. Проблема в том, что конечный файл нужно скомпилировать в файл .exe, но сделать это не получается по непонятным причинам. Вот пример.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget)
import sys
import pyproj

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(250, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Compile')
        self.btn = QPushButton('Press!')
        self.lbl = QLabel()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn)

    def on_btn(self):
        inProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
        outProj = pyproj.Proj("+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
        x1,y1 = 45.387456, 30.524796
        lon,lat = pyproj.transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)

        self.lbl.setText(str(lon) + ' ' + str(lat))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В таком виде файл компилируется. Но при попытке открыть его двойным щелчком на секунду появляется консоль и исчезает, больше ничего не происходит. 
Если убрать импорт pyproj, а также его объекты и методы из скрипта, то все компилируется и работает нормально. То есть проблема в библиотеке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему.

На всякий случай отмечу, что как скрипт python файл запускается без проблем.

Python 3.6, Pyinstaller 3.4, Windows 10 (64-разрядная)

Answer (score 1):

В общем в итоге проблему решила переустановка библиотеки pyproj с последней версии 2.1.3 на более раннюю (версия 1.9.6).
В этом случае все компилируется без проблем.

Answer (score 0):

На enSO есть [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21092414/5308802). Там говорят, что у **PyInstaller** есть трудности в распознании и подгрузке файлов модуля **pyproj**, поэтому для решения проблемы советуют добавить в проект файл `hook-pyproj.py` с таким содержимым:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('pyproj')
```

И поместить этот файл в папку `hooks` в Вашем проекте. Можно поместить и в другую директорию указав до неё путь аргументом `--additional-hooks-dir`.